# Structure to build an auction website?

Tags: web, web-deployment

I plan to build a website which is basically like an auction website with added functionalities, which language should i prefer in terms of cost maintenance, webhosting, easiness to develop etc ?  Are there any templates i can use to get started or like a tutorial ?

Any kind of tips and tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to start by using an extension / plugin to an established CMS otherwise you will spend your time reinventing the wheel.

To get you started, Joomla, WordPress and Drupal all have options you could checkout. Obvioulsy you are looking for a good fit for what you need now and a platform that can be extended to match your future needs.

Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/auction

WordPress: http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=auction

Drupal: https://drupal.org/search/site/auction

For language, all will use PHP + MySQL, they will probably all be in the same ballpark for maintenance costs and hosting requirements. Easiness will no doubt vary ... if your requirements are complex, then there may be more of a learning curve to find a suitable solution.

Good luck!